# Find points as far apart as possible from their nearest neighbor

Tags: coordinate-systems

Let $B$ be a three dimensional box with dimensions $L,W,H$. Suppose I have a finite set $S$ of points in $B$. I want to find the points $p$ in the box that maximize the distance to the nearest point in $S$.

Below I provide some examples for the analogous two dimensional problem.

2D Examples:

For each example the bounds of the box will be `x = [0 -> 10]` and `y = [0 -> 10]`

Les `S` be the set of points in the box.

1. `S=[(0,0),(0,10)]` the point I'm looking for is `(10,5)`

The distance between `(10,5)` and `(0,0)` is `sqrt(125)` and the distance between `(10,5)` and `(0,10)` is also `sqrt(125)`. There doesn't exist any other point on the box that has a distance greater than `sqrt(125)` therefor the point I'm looking for is `(10,5)`

2. `S=[(0,0),(0,2),(0,5)]` the point I'm looking for is `(10,10)`

the reason for this is because the distance between `(10,10)` and `(0,5)` is `sqrt(125)`. Note: The other points in the calculation aren't used in the final distance calculation because I just need to get the greatest distance from the closest point.

3. `S=[(0,0),(10,0),(0,10),(10,10)]` the point I'm looking for `(5,5)`
4. `S=[(5,0),(5,5),(5,10)]` the points I'm looking for are `(0,2.5), (0,7.5), (10,2.5) and (10,7.5)`
5. `S=[(5,5),(5,10),(10,5),(1,0),(2,3),(1,1),(0,0)]` the point I'm looking for is `(10,10)`

The closest points to `(10,10)` are `(5,10)` and `(10,5)` and the distance between `(10,10)` and those points is `5`. This is the point I'm looking for since there doesn't exist any other points in the box that has a greater distance from its closest "neighbors".
`(9.9,10)` has a distance of `4.9` from `(5,10)` and `(10,9.9)` has a distance of `4.9` from `(10,5)` both of which are less than the distance of `5` calculated from `(10,10)`.

Current potential approach:

Let `distance = f(x,y)`
If `S = [(0.5,0.5),(0,1)]` then I can extrapolate the following.

```
Mid point between (0.5,0.5) and (0,1) is (0.25, 0.75).
d = 0 = f(0.5,0.5) = f(0,1)
d = sqrt(0.25^2 + 0.25^2) = f(0.25, 0.75)
0 = f'(0.5,0.5) = f'(0,1)
0 =  f'(0.25,0.75) in the direction of the line between (0.5,0.5) and (0,1)
0 > f''(0.5, 0.5)
0 > f''(0, 1)
0 < f''(0.25, 0.75) in the direction of the line between (0.5,0.5) and (0,1)
```

I'm thinking about getting this information for every point and its closest neighbor, and using this information I'm hoping to be able to extrapolate a function for the shape of distance over the box.

If this is impossible do to degrees of freedom, how many sample distances would I need to calculate from random points in the box to be able extrapolate such a function?

Comment: I don't mind the down vote but could you add a reason so I can improve.

Comment: I  didn't downvote, but would guess it's a combination of (i) Lack of demonstrated effort; (ii) ambiguous mathematical description; (iii) lack of context. <> As written, there are omitted details that affect any prospective answer. What is a 3D grid? Are its dimensions positive integers? How are the given points described, and are there finitely many? Must the points sought lie on a grid of some sort? If so, how is that grid defined?

Comment: I tried to simplify the question down. I had a previous post which I think was overly complicated. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4409546/for-each-point-in-a-set-of-3d-points-get-the-points-that-are-the-furthest-awa

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. There may be "better" ways to draw attention to the original question than by posting a simplified version, such as editing it to clarify, or placing a bounty? <> Either way, I still don't really understand the criteria, based on both the edits here and the linked question. Is the geometric goal to find the largest sphere contained in the rectangular box that does not contain any of the specified points...?

Comment: I don't understand either.Please [edit] the question to show us several small examples in two dimensions, with pictures, showing is the problem statement and the answer for that problem. Are you looking for an algorithm? A geometric argument? I concur with @AndrewD.Hwang that you should not have asked the same question twice. I think you should delete the other one.

Comment: I have edited the question to rephrase it to better express what I _think_  you mean. If these edits suit you, you can remove your first attempts and leave the examples. If I have misunderstood, just remove my edits. You should say "grid" and not "box" only if you want only integer points, and explicitly require integers.

Comment: Thank you, I've also deleted my first post as per peoples suggestions.